# Finding gap between date range Postgres

Tags: postgresql, gaps-and-islands

I have this table and need to find gaps between intervals

Records may be overlapping.

```
user |    start_time            |     end_time
user1|2018-09-26T02:16:52.023453|2018-09-26T03:12:04.404477
user1|2018-09-25T22:15:49.593296|2018-09-26T00:15:52.016497
user1|2018-09-25T20:13:02.358192|2018-09-25T22:15:49.593296
```

Expected output will be

```
 user |    start_time            |     end_time
 user1|2018-09-26T00:15:52.016497|2018-09-26T02:16:52.023453
```

Comment: What do you mean gap between date? could you explain more detail about your logic?'

Comment: the gap between consecutive date range (which the start_time, end-time) @D-Shih

Comment: Check window functions `LEAD` and `LAG` - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-window.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=57be9d651cf571d6712432d2176a14c6)

You can use the `lag` window function (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html). This function moves a value from a previous row into the current. Now it is possible to compare the moves `end_time` with the current `start_time` and check for the gap.

```
SELECT
    "user",
    prev_end_time as gap_start_time,
    start_time as gap_end_time
FROM (
    SELECT 
        *, 
        lag(end_time) OVER (PARTITION BY "user" ORDER BY start_time) as prev_end_time
    FROM time_intervals 
    ORDER BY start_time
) s
WHERE start_time > prev_end_time
```

**Result**

```
user    gap_start_time               gap_end_time
user1   2018-09-26 00:15:52.016497   2018-09-26 02:16:52.023453
```

---

Notice that "user" is a **reserved word** in Postgres. You should better use another column name.

Comment: so moving the end date to the next row and comparing that basically to the start date of that row?

Comment: That's what it does :)

Comment: cool, sorry another question, what exactly does the `PARTITION` do?

Comment: I gave a link to the window function tutorial. You should read it. The window function partitions the table.  It's a kind of grouping. If you have 2 users the function would to the "row shift" only within each user group separately because it would not make any sense to search gaps over two users, wouldn't it? If the user name doesn't matter you would only need the `ORDER BY` clause. Example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=90b11211f083992e52f2694ee305a506

Comment: make sense, it's like a GROUP BY.

Comment: Yes. But with the benefit that you don't have to aggregate all columns (as shown in the tutorial)